# Overly long edge in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I have this tree:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=50pt]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30pt]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=25pt]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=15pt]
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\Tree [.\node(a1){$\ \Delta^1$};
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_1$};
[.{ $q_1\cdot\Delta^2$}
    \edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_5$};
    {}
    \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_6$};
    [.{$q_6\cdot\Delta^7$} % TODO add Cartesian product here
        \edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_{13}$};
        {}
        \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{14}$}; 
        {}
        \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{15}$}; 
        {}
        ]
    ]
%
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_2$};
[. {$q_2\cdot\Delta^3$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_7$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_8$};
        {} 
]
]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\Tree [.\node(a2){$\ \Delta^2$};
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_3$};
[. {$q_3\cdot\Delta^5$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_9$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{10}$};
        {} 
]
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{4}$};
[. {$q_4\cdot\Delta^6$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_{11}$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{12}$};
        {} 
]
]
\end{scope}
\path (a1) -- node {$\times$} (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But, as can hopefully be seen in this pic, the edge from `$q_1\cdot\Delta^2$` is too long compared to other edges at the same level. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can add `\vphantom{$q_6\cdot\Delta^7$}` to the node after that edge, and it will be the same length, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gonzalo's answer is a nice way if you don't mind switching to the `forest` package. However, if you want to keep the code you have already written and continue using `tikz-qtree`, you can add `\vphantom{$q_6\cdot\Delta^7$}` to the node after that edge. This will add invisible vertical space in that node that is the same height as the vertical space in its sister node.

### Result

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=50pt]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30pt]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=25pt]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=15pt]
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\Tree [.\node(a1){$\ \Delta^1$};
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_1$};
[.{ $q_1\cdot\Delta^2$}
    \edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_5$};
    {\vphantom{$q_6\cdot\Delta^7$}}
    \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_6$};
    [.{$q_6\cdot\Delta^7$} % TODO add Cartesian product here
        \edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_{13}$};
        {}
        \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{14}$}; 
        {}
        \edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{15}$}; 
        {}
        ]
    ]
%
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_2$};
[. {$q_2\cdot\Delta^3$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_7$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_8$};
        {} 
]
]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\Tree [.\node(a2){$\ \Delta^2$};
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_3$};
[. {$q_3\cdot\Delta^5$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_9$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{10}$};
        {} 
]
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{4}$};
[. {$q_4\cdot\Delta^6$}
\edge node[auto=right,scale=0.7]{$q_{11}$};
        {} 
\edge node[auto=left,scale=0.7]{$q_{12}$};
        {} 
]
]
\end{scope}
\path (a1) -- node {$\times$} (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

An nice answer was provided by Adam Liter using `tikz-qtree`, but here I want to show an alternative approach using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; notice, in particular, the shorter, cleaner code; the direct issue in the question was addressed here in a different way using the text height key for the nodes so they will all have the same height independently of their content:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\forestset{
leftedge/.style={
  edge label={node[inner sep=1pt,midway,auto,swap,font=\scriptsize]{$#1$}}
  },
rightedge/.style={
  edge label={node[inner sep=1pt,midway,auto,font=\scriptsize]{$#1$}}
  }
}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  math content,
  text height=2ex,
  l sep=25pt,
  s sep=20pt,
  where level={3}{s sep=30pt}{}
}
[,phantom,
  [\ \Delta^1
    [q_{1}\cdot\Delta^{2},leftedge={q_{1}}
      [,leftedge={q_{5}}
      ]
      [q_{6}\cdot\Delta^{7},rightedge={q_{6}}
        [,leftedge={q_{13}}]
        [,rightedge={q_{14}}]
        [,rightedge={q_{15}}]
      ]
    ]
    [q_{2}\cdot\Delta^{3},rightedge={q_{2}}
      [,leftedge={q_{7}}
      ]
      [,rightedge={q_{8}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [\ \Delta^2
    [q_{3}\cdot\Delta^{5},leftedge={q_{3}}
      [,leftedge={q_{9}}
      ]
      [,rightedge={q_{10}}
      ]
    ]
    [q_{4}\cdot\Delta^{6},rightedge={q_{4}}
      [,leftedge={q_{11}}
      ]
      [,rightedge={q_{12}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment! I upvoted, and I might check out forest in the future, but for now, my paper deadline makes me prefer to stick with what I have :)